# How to work with advanced entities which does not fit table data in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Lets say we have a Person entity which fits table exactly:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }

}
```

Now user have a type, and only if user is of specific type I want to be able to find out what is the Name of that type that person is. Right now I just add extra property on to the entity:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }

}
```

But I want to let my entities stay as clean as possible.

Do I need to create a separate "advanced entities" classes for this cases or how do I get around those cases?

PS. I am using stored procedures.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do?  Why does adding one extra property to the model make it unclean?  Is this a simplified example?  What is the desired behavior?

Comment: Additional properties are fine.  Just make sure their values are logically in sync.  A single backing variable sounds like a good approach. For example, the TypeName getter could decide based on underlying value of Type.

Comment: Is there a specific version of ASP.NET MVC you are targeting? If so, include the tag for that specific version. If not, include only the non-versioned tag, `asp.net-mvc`, as I've edited your question to have. Do not use `model-view-controller` unless you have a question pertaining to the pattern itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear but i think you are mixing view models with entities. If you want to store your user "Type" into the database then, yes you have to add a new field in your entity ( or use partial classes ) OR if you are using database first then add the field in your table and refresh your edmx .  If you don't want to store it in database, just create a view model and use it on our UI.

Answer (score 0):

Change that name to something specific about a person, whatever you want to track about a person (HairColor, EyeColor, Nationality, Size)  anything but just plain "Type", which is a system base class in C#.

Answer (score 0):

yes... use partial clases with extended properties inside them

Comment: This would probably be better if you gave a short example.